# Dropdown with delete & add in .Net Core 2.0 MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I wonder if there is a pretty way of creating a dropdown, in .Net Core 2.0 MVC, where the items can be added or deleted? I have found multiple solutions for adding, but none that includes delete. Below is a mockup that illustrates how I envision it.

[image]

Clicking on the name will select it. Clicking on the red crossed box will delete the item (with underlying WCF backend delete). Clicking "Other" will show a new textbox where a new value can be entered.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC, but everything with HTML, JS and CSS.

Comment: Can't you see it as an MVC issue when it is preferably solved in an MVC surrounding where MVC is used to generate HTML, JS and CSS?

Comment: MVC hardly generates any HTML, JS and CSS, except around form elements and their validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin like [Select2](https://select2.org/tagging) that allow to delete (in tagging mode) and adding values.
There are [several](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) [others](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) jQuery plugins to chose.

[image]